# Redirect to page/url, controlled by user in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect/send users, 'controlled' by username in `.htaccess`?

Example:

- If UserA logs in then, UserA is sent to `1234.html`
- IF UserB logs in then, UserB is sent to `9876.html`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are protecting the root directory with HTTP authentication then you can do something like the following in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# UserA redirected to "/1234.html"
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} =UserA
RewriteRule !^1234\.html$ /1234.html [R,L]

# UserB redirected to "/9876.html"
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} =UserB
RewriteRule !^9876\.html$ /9876.html [R,L]
```

If UserA is logged in and accesses this directory then they are redirected (302 - temporary) to `/1234.html`. Otherwise, if UserB is logged in they are redirected to `/9876.html`.

The *CondPattern*, eg. `=UserA` (`=` prefix), is an exact string comparison for "UserA" (case-sensitive).

The negated (`!`) `RewriteRule` *pattern*, eg. `!^1234\.html$` checks that the request is not already for `1234.html` (ie. the target file), otherwise we would get a redirect loop.

Note that the user is always redirected (forced) to the respective file/page. If the user should only be redirected to the file when they *first* login then you will need another condition (perhaps based on a cookie) to determine that they have already visited that file.

Comment: This works just as I hoped would do :-)
Thank you

Comment: @Per You're welcome. Please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer (to help other readers and to remove the question from the unanswered question queue - you also get some "rep"). Once you have 15 rep you can also upvote answers that you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)